# Should we separate the ssis packages between several projects in our Solution?

Tags: design-patterns, visual-studio-2015, ssis, data-warehouse

I use `SSIS2012`. I have created three schema in my Data warehouse(`STG`, `TRSF`, `DW`).

The STG schema is for staging tables. All my source file are the CSV files. I am transferring the data from my source to each table in stg schema. I have a separate package for each tables (For example: If i have 20 csv files, I will have 20 packages and i will populate 20 tables in stg schema)

After that, I am transferring `stg` schema to `trsf` schema. During those process i have my business. I do lookup for FK and other business rules will be applied in this level. The same as privious example if I have 20 tables in `stg` schema, I will have 20 packages and I will fill 20 tables in `trsf` schema.

In third step I will transfer the data from `trsf` schema to `dw` schema. Here also I have 20 packages.

At end, I will have 20 package for cleaning the tables in `stg` schema.

I create 4 packages for each transformation between csv files and the tables in `dw` schema.

I would like to know if it is good idea to create 4 separate projects for each step? Because now, I have 80 packages in one project and it can be grow up more.

Comment: Personally I would keep my packages together, but if it causes problems for you, separate them out.

Comment: The most important thing here is organisation.  As long as you know what your packages do, and can control the order in which they execute; I would say the rest does not matter.  Off-topic; if each of the schemas has 20 tables, does that mean the final dw tables look a lot like the raw data?  If you are not [transforming your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation), are the `trsf` and `dw` schemas bringing anything to the party?

Comment: @destination-data: I appreciate your answer. I was just  talking about dimension tables. I have transformation for my fact table. I have a several sql jobs. those are 4 steps for executing 4 package in order. (Staging/ TRSF/DW/Cleanning)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the projects together. However to separate them, I would keep separate parent jobs for Landing, Staging and the Data Warehouse. And you could control these Parent jobs by a Master Parent jobs..This would give you freedom to run individual stages independently.

Another suggestion, I would suggest you separate the Landing, Staging and the Data Warehouse in separate databases. Believe me it would help you in the long run.

Cheers
Nithin

Comment: My problem is about number of package in the project. In my project there are more than 80 package and it will be increased in future. Do you have any idea to separate them?

Comment: Hi Ardalan We use naming conventions to separate packages.. For eg: '101_Extract_Source_System_Name', '600_Fact_Business_Activity'. Since we used numbers in our package names, we could order the packages. However in SSIS 2012, the packages are all jumbled up when you open them initially, you could sort them at the project level in VS. When you deploy them they will always stay in the order of the numbers.