# VS 2015 SSIS project with virtual subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl, solution-explorer

we develop SSIS packages in larger scales. Thus a single solution/project of ours holds in most cases more than 200 single packages. You may imagine, that keeping track of them is not easy.

To enhance that, we would like to view these packages in different virtual supfolders. Say [Hubs], [Links], and [Satellites] for a Datawald-project.

Splitting the projects and/or relocating the packages is not an option.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Best regards

Saxxon

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I have asked the same question.

you can find it here : 
[Should we separate the ssis packages between several projects in our Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148184/should-we-separate-the-ssis-packages-between-several-projects-in-our-solution)

At the end, I have separated the package in several project. I think it is the only possibility with VS2015.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Alas, splitting the project is not an option for us. It looks like we need to stick to our naming convention for the packages to keep them in order.

Comment: Naming convention is another solution. But in our project we have preferred to separate the package. One project for staging package one project for TRSF package and one project for DW package.Good look.